# Errors when I try to validate input in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, validation, typescript, angular-validation

I am trying to validate input

```
    <md-input-container class="name-input">
                <input type="text" mdInput [(ngModel)]="tileName"  #tileNameInput="ngModel" 
                      id="tileNameInput" name="tileNameInput" 
                      required placeholder="{{ 'Name' | translate }}"/>
                <md-error *ngIf="v.errors.required">Tile Name is required</md-error>
            </md-input-container>
```

and I got error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined
>           at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HeaderComponent.html:104)
>           at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12784)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12122)
>           at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12485)
>           at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12443)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12123)
>           at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12485)
>           at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12417)
>           at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12128)
>           at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12485)

Can somebody helps me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the name of input field instead of `v`, like: `*ngIf="tileNameInput.errors.required"`